# Check if a User type exists in ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Course Model which contains a user who creates the course and contains a `enrolled` ManyToManyField which lets users enroll in the course.

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='course_owner')
    enrolled = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    ...
```

The user model contains two types - Teacher (Created the course) and Student (enrolls)

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want a MyCourses View where the teacher can view his created_courses and the student can view his enrolled courses.

```py
def MyCourses(request):
    user = request.user
    courses = Course.objects.filter(user=user)

    context = {
        'courses': courses
    }

    return render(request, 'classroom/mycourses.html', context)
```

This works for the teacher part but how I can check if a student is enrolled in the course?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra condition and use a logical or:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def MyCourses(request):
    user = request.user
    courses = Course.objects.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(enrolled=user))

    context = {
        'courses': courses
    }

    return render(request, 'classroom/mycourses.html', context)
```

to prevent loading the same `Course` multiple times, you can use [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
from django.db.models import Q

def MyCourses(request):
    user = request.user
    courses = Course.objects.filter(Q(user=user) | Q(enrolled=user)).distinct()

    context = {
        'courses': courses
    }

    return render(request, 'classroom/mycourses.html', context)
```